# How do you remove row numbers for a QTableView in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am using a QTableView to display instructions for a low level emulator.

However, the rows index from 1 whereas the instructions index from 0.
I either need to remove the row numbers and add an extra column which I can fill with the 0 indexed instruction number of change the row numbers so they index from 0.

I cannot see how to do either, am I just being blind?

Comment: Are you using a `QListView` or a `QTableView`?

Comment: *sigh* - sorry was distracted by my children as I was typing!  It is a QTableView, have edited the question.  Thanks!

Comment: You might be right, I tried various phrases but not "index number".

Comment: Well, at least you have a solution :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
yourtable->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
```

to hide the row numbers.